# Runtime exception when calling C++/CLI derived class

Tags: c++-cli

## Edited by the OP 5 August 2014:

Much simplified code:

```
public ref class CXmlWriter : public System::Xml::XmlTextWriter
{
public:
    CXmlWriter(System::String ^sFilename) : XmlTextWriter(sFilename, System::Text::Encoding::Unicode)
        {
        }

    ~CXmlWriter()
        {
        }
};
```

Call a function containing code that instantiates CXmlWriter (you don't have to execute that instantiation code) and you get the exception.
Comment out the destructor and you don't get the exception. Making the destructor virtual doesn't fix it.

## End of edit

I am using Version 4 of the .NET framework.

I have C++/CLI classes CXmlWriter derived from System::Xml::XmlTextWriter and CMinMaxXmlWriter derived from CXmlWriter.
Implementation is pretty simple for both classes and everything compiles without error. However, when I try to instantiate CMinMaxXmlWriter at runtime I get a TypeLoadException with the error message:

> Declaration referenced in a method implementation cannot be a final method

with a mention of CXmlWriter

This used to work without any problem in Version 2 of the framework.

Here's the header for CXmlWriter:

```
public ref class CXmlWriter : public System::Xml::XmlTextWriter
{
public:
    CXmlWriter(System::String ^sFilename);
    ~CXmlWriter();
    !CXmlWriter() {}

    virtual bool    Open();
    virtual void    Close() override;    

    virtual bool    WriteValueAndAttribute(System::String ^sElementName, System::String ^sElementValue, System::String ^sAttrName, System::String ^sAttrValue);
    virtual bool    WriteValueAndAttribute(System::String ^sElementName, double dElementValue, System::String ^sAttrName, System::String ^sAttrValue);

protected:
    bool                    m_bIsOpen;
};
```

CMinMaxXmlWriter is defined in a very similar way.

Please can someone explain why the exception occurs and what I should do to avoid it.

Comment: If it compiles without error, it's unlikely that the issue is with the header file. Please post a self-contained example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Please see my edits to the original question above.